# Deploying Azure webjobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

When using VS.NET to deploy an Azure WebJob I see it gets copied to:

/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/continuous/[nameofjob]

So this seems to sit inside the webapp we have there, which I think is not correct, since it might not even be related to this webapp.

But I also see there's another folder on the root folder here:

/site/jobs/Continuous

So I guess I'd like to deploy here and not inside the webapp.
I've been looking around in VS.NET but can't find where this can be setup.
I've seen some references to what I'm trying to do here for example:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs

so my question is wheter this is possible to be done from within VS.NET "Publish as Azure WebJob" or it needs to be done manually.
And if manually, is it just a matter of copy files over this folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use different folder to deploy WebJobs. Yes, you could set the `WEBJOBS_ROOT_PATH` environment in the Application Setting.

Actually the `WEBJOBS_ROOT_PATH` value it's not must be `d:\home\site\jobs\`, it's just a folder to deploy WebJobs, the default WebJob worling directory `%TEMP%\jobs\{job type}\{job name}\{random name}`. So you could also set the value like `D:\home\site\repository`(you still could set it with `d:\home\site\jobs\`).

[image]

Save the settings. Then you could deploy the zip file from portal, if you deploy continuous webjob it will create the continuous folder.

[image]

[image]

> wheter this is possible to be done from within VS.NET "Publish as
>   Azure WebJob"

The answer is no, from the wiki you post you could know **this's useful when using Run-From-Zip**. So for now you have to deploy the zip file, you could do it on the portal. And if you have set the `WEBJOBS_ROOT_PATH` value, the deployment folder is still `d:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs`, then you couldn't find it on the portal WebJob page.

Comment: @vmasanas, if this works, please mark it as the answer. Thanks.