# Azure WebJobs CD ereasing wwwroot content

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, continuous-delivery

I'm publishing 2 web jobs to the respective paths:

[image: Azure AppService Configuration]

But, every time, the content inside `site\wwwroot` is erased, and I have an API project published there, so, every time I need to republish the API after.

I can't find a solution anywhere about this, why is this happening?

This is my web jobs CD:

[image: WebJob Cd Tasks]

I was expecting having to republish my API every time I publish my web job.

Comment: So every time you publish your project, your webjob is deleted; Is that the case?

Comment: @hiFI no, my webapi, in the wwwroot folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue when I tried to deploy files to the Virtual application path, and I found the `site\wwwroot` folder will be back to the old last version.

#### Workaround

If I change the task version from `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4` to `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3`, it works and will not make change to the files in the `site\wwwroot` folder. I also find a known issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13946) for your reference.

[image]

Comment: OMFG this is crazy, thank you a lot, this is exactly the bug I'm dealing with, for days, its been too much time having this trouble, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order for **`Webjobs`** to deploy properly, You need to build them together in the **`app folder`** and then ***Publish the build artifact to the Azure Web App service.***

Refer my SO answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77502700/how-to-deploy-a-webjob-from-a-pipeline/77507158#).

*My Azure DevOps yaml pipeline:-*

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

jobs:
- job: BuildAndDeployWebJobs
  displayName: 'Build and Deploy Web Jobs'

  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '3.x'
      installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: false
      projects: '**/Webjob1.csproj'
      arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/WebJob1'
      zipAfterPublish: false
      modifyOutputPath: false

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: true
      projects: '**/WebJobExample.WebJob.csproj'
      arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/WebJobExample'
      zipAfterPublish: false
      modifyOutputPath: false

  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output'
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
      replaceExistingArchive: true

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      ArtifactName: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'Container'

  - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
    inputs:
      ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
      azureSubscription: 'xxx subscription (xxxxxxxxx97cb2a7)'
      appType: 'webApp'
      WebAppName: 'siliconwebapp098'
      packageForLinux: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      JSONFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
```

I have build both the **WebJobs separately** and then published the **build artifact** to the **Azure Web app** above.

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***Release pipeline:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I think I wasn't clear, I have no problem with my other webjob, just with my webapi, that is published in the site/wwwroot folder. The webjobs are going to site/jobs and they're okay, but when I publish any webjob, the content inside sites/wwwroot, that are not in use by any webjob, is ereased.

Comment: I see, Did you build the Webapi along with the Webjob together and tried publishing it? As in above github repository, I have built Web app and Webjob together and published the artifact in the Azure Web app, This allowed me to Run the App in your case API and the Webjob got created separately

Comment: I have no access to do it, cause in another azure subscription, it works, as far as I know, I'm using the same configurations in the 2 subscriptions. But, a long time ago, I was using the same sites/wwwroot directory for both, webjobs and webapi, then, the jobs were going to the sites/wwwroot/app_data folder, but, everytime I published a webjob, the content inside wwwroot was lost. Then, I moved to an virtual path, as i saw here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55331811/23259416, it worked in my old azure subscription, but, in the current subscription Im working, i did the same and it doesnt work